# Decoding a continuous stream of data in a thread without blocking the receiver

Tags: c#, multithreading, ftdi

I am using a UART to USB communication, FTDI chip in my project.

I receive a continuous stream of data from the UART. I am suppose to decode the receive data. I have enabled the event handler for received Char from the FTDI chip. So whenever i receiver any data, its coming to this separate thread.

```
//Event Wait Handle
private EventWaitHandle DataReceived = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
```

I make use of a background worker,

```
BackgroundWorker DataHandler = new BackgroundWorker();
DataHandler.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DataHandler_DoWork);
```

Start the separate thread for reading

```
if (!DataHandler.IsBusy)
    DataHandler.RunWorkerAsync();
```

What i notice is the DecodeData function blocks the receiving of the data while decoding the received data.Is there any way i can do this task?

Here is the function:

```
void DataHandler_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UInt32 numBytes = 0;
    byte[] readArray = new byte[1025];
    // Loop forever
    for (; ; )
    {
        // Wait for a FT_EVENT_RXCHAR event
        if (DataReceived.WaitOne(100))
        {
            // Find out how many bytes have been received
            if ((ftStatus = _ftdiHelper.GetDataBytes(this, ref numBytes)) != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Read the bytes out
            if ((ftStatus = _ftdiHelper.ReadFromFTDI(readArray, numBytes, ref numBytes)) != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                continue;
            }
            _decodeResponse.DecodeData(this, readArray);
            Array.Clear(readArray, 0, readArray.Length);
        }

        if (DataHandler.CancellationPending)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need another thread - read in one, process in the other.

Comment: How do i pass the data , in my case ReadArray to that thread?

Comment: You could use a concurrent queue, for example.

Comment: Is there any example code for this?for making a separate thread and passing the readArray everytime i receive a databyte? can you please post the link here?

Comment: This is a classic 'producer-consumer' use case. Use different threads for consumer and producer(s) and a `BlockingCollection` and the `Add` and `GetConsumingEnumerable()` methods. Read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) for details.

Comment: Difficult to understand mate..:( any simpler way of execution..i don't have much experience in multi threads..